# How to Change Some Application Property During Creating War Using Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, war, properties-file

I am building a web application. I have several environment for deployment, like: local, dev, stg, prod.

Suppose my `application.properties` file as follow

```
foo.bar = fooBar
foo.another = another
foo.var = fooVar
```

And my `application-dev.properties` as follow

```
foo.var = fooDevEnv
```

I want the `application.properties` which will include in war for dev environment as follow:

```
foo.bar = fooBar
foo.another = another
foo.var = fooDevEnv #this should comes from application-dev.properties
```

How can I do this with gradle?

My current solution is to create separate file for each environment in separate folder and copy then during war building. But the problem is I have to copy all the common properties in each file. script is follow:

```
def env = project.properties['env'] ?: "local"
war {
    webInf {
        from('./config/' + env) {
            include 'application.properties' into 'classes'
        }
    }
    archiveName = 'my-app-' + env + '.war'
}
```

I am using gradle 4.1

Comment: Have you already seen resources filtering: http://blog.codeleak.pl/2015/11/spring-boot-with-gradle-and-resource.html ?

Comment: Have you got your answer for this question?